# Moving an element using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've built a small Javascript application which can move an SVG element, i've now tried to rebuild it using image elements for the controls rather than SVG shapes.

**Javascript + jQuery**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">         
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var panning = false;
        var direction;

        function startPan(dir){
            panning = true;
            direction = dir;
        }  

        function stopPan(){
            panning = false;
        }

        function pan(){  
            var item = $("#moveme"); 
            var x = item.position().left; 
            var y = item.position().top;            
            var amount = 1;
            if(direction == "left"){
                x -= amount;
            } else if (direction == "right"){
                x += amount ;
            } else if (direction == "up"){
                y -= amount;
            } else if (direction == "down"){
                y += amount;
            }

            item.css("left", x);
            item.css("top", y);
        }

        function panLoop(){          
            if(panning == true){      
                pan();
            }
        }
        setInterval(panLoop,100);
    });
</script>

<style>
    .button:hover{
        opacity: 0.5;
    }

    .button{
        position: absolute;
    }

    .compass{
        position: absolute;
    }

    div.pan{
        position: absolute;
        width: 90px;
        height: 90px;
    }

    #moveme{
        position: absolute;
        top: 200px;
        left: 200px;
    }
</style>

<div class="pan">
    <img class="button"
         style="top: 0px; left: 30px;"
         src="images/tu.png"
         onmouseover="startPan('up')"
         onmouseout="stopPan()" />
    <img class="button" 
         style="top: 30px; right: 0px;"         
         src="images/tr.png"
         onmouseover="startPan('right')"
         onmouseout="stopPan()" />     

    <img class="button" 
         style="bottom: 0px; left: 30px;"         
         src="images/td.png"
         onmouseover="startPan('down')"
         onmouseout="stopPan()" />       

    <img class="button" 
         style="top: 30px; left: 0px;"         
         src="images/tl.png"
         onmouseover="startPan('left')"
         onmouseout="stopPan()" />

    <img class="compass"
         style="top: 21px; left: 21px;"
         src="images/c.png"/>

</div>

<div id="moveme">
    HELLo
</div>
```

However it's not calling the mouseover event, and I can't figure out why....

Here is the version using SVG:

[**Working version using Javascript + SVG**](http://jtbrown.me.uk/assets/unrelated/pan.php)

**Working version:**
[Working without SVG](http://jtbrown.me.uk/assets/unrelated/pan/pan.html)

Comment: Isn't case important here? i.e. onMouseOver? Otherwise maybe try it on a div wrapping the img tags, or even use divs only and set the images as their back-ground image.

Comment: The case of event handlers [in this case](http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/BYtCC/) does not matter. HOWEVER, the OP should be using [event handlers](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/) added by jQuery, not added in the markup, IMO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See here http://jsbin.com/ecihij/edit#source

When you write your functions you do not need to put them inside the jQuery document Ready section

Jarred is right you should also be using jQuery event handers see updated example here
http://jsbin.com/ecihij/2/edit.

And code below

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>


<style>
    .button:hover{
        opacity: 0.5;
    }

    .button{
        position: absolute;
    }

    .compass{
        position: absolute;
    }

    div.pan{
        position: absolute;
        width: 90px;
        height: 90px;
    }

    #moveme{
        position: absolute;
        top: 200px;
        left: 200px;
    }
</style>

<script class="jsbin" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
<!--[if IE]>
  <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<style>
  article, aside, figure, footer, header, hgroup, 
  menu, nav, section { display: block; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="pan">


    <p class="button bup" style="top: 0px; left: 30px;" > up</p>

    <p  class="button bright" syle="top: 30px; right: 0px;" >right </p>  


    <p  class="button bdown" style="bottom: 0px; left: 30px;">down </p>     

    <p class="button bleft" style="top: 30px; left: 0px;" >left </p>

    <p  class="compass" style="top: 21px; left: 21px;">compass </p>

</div>

<div id="moveme">
    HELLo
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
         var panning = false;
        var direction;

function startPan(dir){
            panning = true;
            direction = dir;
        }  

        function stopPan(){
            panning = false;
        }

        function pan(){  
            var item = $("#moveme"); 
            var x = item.position().left; 
            var y = item.position().top;            
            var amount = 1;
            if(direction == "left"){
                x -= amount;
            } else if (direction == "right"){
                x += amount ;
            } else if (direction == "up"){
                y -= amount;
            } else if (direction == "down"){
                y += amount;
            }

            item.css("left", x);
            item.css("top", y);
        }

        function panLoop(){          
            if(panning === true){      
                pan();
            }
        }

     setInterval(panLoop,100);

$(document).ready(function(){


  $('.bup').mouseover(function(){  startPan('up');  }).mouseout(stopPan); 
  $('.bright').mouseover(function(){  startPan('right');  }).mouseout(stopPan); 
  $('.bleft').mouseover(function(){  startPan('left');  }).mouseout(stopPan); 
  $('.bdown').mouseover(function(){  startPan('down');  }).mouseout(stopPan); 



    });
```

Comment: Please put the relevant code within your answer, not just in a link. :)

Comment: I think he's on the money here though, move them out of that part and I reckon you'll be good to go.

Comment: Hey i've uploaded it as an example, and so that it's available to download if you like.

http://jtbrown.me.uk/assets/unrelated/pan/pan.html